# Rewrite rule for redirect url on different domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to point subdomain.domain.net to www.subdfgomain.com or whaterver , i try with htaccess rule but not getting result , Please help !!

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /project/projectname/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project/projectname/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^projectname.domain.net
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.another.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Why are you not showing WP rules in your code and what error are you getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error but this Rewrite rule not appear anything in site

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have other rules also?

Comment: see now i have updated with all defined rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have managed through web.config , and now it's working .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <action type="None" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="None" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="WordPress Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep redirect before rewrite rules. Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/projectname/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^projectname\.domain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.another.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project/projectname/index.php [L]
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `[NC] L NE`? can you share any resource to learn more about this?

Comment: Sure you check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html and then http://askapache.com

Comment: `NC - Ignore Case comparison, NE - No Encoding, L - Last rule in current loop`.

Comment: How do you think `No p is not working` will help anybody find out what's wrong? Respond to each of these questions. Q1. What URL did you try and didn't work? Q2. What error did you get? Q3. Where is this .htaccess located? Q4. Is your .htaccess exactly as I have in my answer OR you have other code too?

Comment: i hava added this htaccess with my original domain url in "projectname.domain.net" root , i checked after update htaccess file no any error or no any redirection will happen .

Comment: There were 4 questions in my previous comment. I will dig further if you provide all the answers.

Comment: A1 ) yes i have try and not working
A2) No any error
A3) .htaccess is located root folder where all wordpress folder and files i.e wp-admin,wp-include etc
A4) in htaccss exactly follow your code just replacement with original url's , i have no added in more code 

and i see that htaccess is not render anything instead of that web.config file is their .

Comment: You still didn't tell what is the **full URL** you tried that didn't redirect to `http://www.another.com`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60089/discussion-between-gayatri-and-anubhava).

Comment: I am on a call right now. Will be free after 1 hour for chat.